# .htaccess 301 Redirect + URL Rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I got a .htaccess that pretty much looks like this:

```
# disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

# start rewrites
RewriteEngine on

Redirect 301 /someoldpage.php http://example.com/fancyurl

# if not a file, and not a directory, reroute through index as normal page
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

What I want to accomplish is that the url is rewritten also when someone is trying to access an old 301 redirectred url, so when going to http://example.com//someoldpage.php you see the url http://example.com/fancyurl and NOT like now: http://example.com/index.php?page=fancyurl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Redirect` is part of mod_alias, while the rewrite stuff is part of mod_rewrite. The two different modules both get applied to the same request and thus causing it to redirect and rewrite at the same time. What you want to do is have it redirect if the request is `/someoldpage.pjp` and **not** rewrite to index.php, so you need to use only mod_rewrite here:

```
# disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

# start rewrites
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^someoldpage\.php$ http://example.com/fancyurl [L,R=301]

# if not a file, and not a directory, reroute through index as normal page
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I Struck with this problem and got a solution in my case, to rewrite the url from `example.com/about.php` to `example.com/about` with the following code in your htaccess.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]
```

Comment: This might be working (didn't try) in the case you want to just cut off the file extension, but not if you want to send someone to a renamed page, for example old link /all-about-us.php and new link /about